# SQL database trigger procedure

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

Create a trigger (UpdateTrigger) that outputs a message saying "Student record is going to be updated" Before the update takes place on a student table

Then update table StudentsInfo
by incrementing StudentsUpdated Value by one.

I need to figure out a way to put the update with the incremented value of one into the same sql statement but I can't get it to work. I've tried a million different ways. Got the answer ty!

```
create or replace trigger update_studentsinfo
       before update on studentsinfo for each row
         begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Student Record is going to be updated');
    :new.studentsupdated := :old.studentsupdated +1;
         End;
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger should be BEFORE UPDATE and FOR EACH ROW

See

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_studentsupdated
  BEFORE UPDATE ON studentsinfo FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DBMS_output.put_line('Student Record is going to be updated');
 Set studentsupdated= :new.studentsupdated + :old.studentsupdated; 
END;


Error at line 3: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


1. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_studentsupdated
2.   BEFORE UPDATE ON studentsinfo FOR EACH ROW
3. BEGIN
4.     DBMS_output.put_line('Student Record is going to be updated');
5.  Set studentsupdated= :new.studentsupdated + :old.studentsupdated;

Comment: i did this now & its still not running

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_studentsinfo
    BEFORE UPDATE OF studentsupdated ON studentsinfo for each row 

    BEGIN
    IF UPDATING (:new.studentsupdated) THEN
    DBMS_output.put_line('Student Record is going to be updated');
    SET :new.studentsupdated := :old.studentsupdated + 1; 
    END;
    /

Comment: How do you say, its not running or any errors do you find

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to refer the names with fully qualified name in oracle. in this case studentsupdated is your table. I recommend that you create the trigger with oracle IDE and use the generated scripts. I hope this will help you with your problem.

Comment: I figured it out - ill edit the question with my answer thank you

Comment: ha ha you don't need to edit the problem in the question. if you just accept my answer and leave the question problem visible, people can find their problems. but it's OK :) because you're new to Stack Overflow, you don't know how it works. thank you.

Comment: besides that if everyone see my answer and your edited version of question then thinks my answer is wrong :D

Comment: It's completely OK ;)

Comment: he he Sorry, Stack Overflow doesn't allow you to chat with me because your reputation is too low. I can not leave may e-mail address here in order to help you. damn it Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not a good idea to leave your e-mail in public.Now how can you recognized if it's a message from me? :))

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with "Before update on"

Comment: still says invalid trigger specification